# Tables Unaligned

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make my tables aligned, however the last table on the right wont align properly. I've tried using div and float. Those both do not work, or I may have not used it properly. How do I fix this? Im using different tables for each content because the cell padding looks odd.

[image]

```css
#div1 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 450px
}

#div2 {
  width: 20%;
  float: center;
}

#div3 {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 400px
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1016525603668762635/1023594193345581076/DEC_AVE.png" width=2 98 height=4 21 alt="Dec Ave"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="font-size:30px; color:rgb(10, 7, 96);" class="csize">DECEMBER AVENUE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="desc">LOCATION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=left class="dates">JUNE 28, 2022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=left><input class="buybutton" type="submit" value="Buy Tickets">
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://images1.smtickets.com/images/portrait_18082022203132.jpg" width=2 98 height=4 21 alt="TOMORROW X TOGETHER"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="font-size:30px; color:rgb(10, 7, 96);" class="csize">TOMORROW X TO...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="desc">LOCATION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=left class="dates">OCT 27-28, 2022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=left><input class="buybutton" type="submit" value="Buy Tickets">
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://images1.smtickets.com/images/portrait_12042022174844.jpg" width=2 98 height=4 21 alt="TOMORROW X TOGETHER"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="font-size:30px; color:rgb(10, 7, 96);" class="csize">RUSS THE JOURN...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="desc">LOCATION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=left class="dates">NOV 05, 2022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=left><input class="buybutton" type="submit" value="Buy Tickets">
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's almost 2023. Don't use tables for layout. Use tables to display tabular data. Use CSS for layout

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
display: flex
flex-direction: column
```

on the three divs or try using

```
display: inline-block
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you really want is just a vertical alignment of the items (in other words, you don't really need a 'table', just items in a grid)
So in this case, use `display:flex` (flex boxes) on a `<div>` element and put all your items in it way. You also get rid of boilerplate for the `table`, `tbody`, `tr` and `td`. (It makes no sense to use a table but all table rows only have one element)

html like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child-element">
         <img ...>...</img>
         ...
    </div>
    <div class="child-element">
         <img ...>...</img>
         ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center; /* centers everything */
}
.child-element{
   /* add optional margins, paddings etc settings
}
```

This will make it responsive to how large the page is as well.